# Python: how to apply a function with condition on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df
     time   case1   case2   case3
0     5     house   bank     atm
1     3     bank    house  pharmacy
2     10    bank    bank     atm
3     20    house  pharmacy  house
```

I want to associate to each case a probability based on the time and the case. Here we have the average value and the standard deviation for each category. So, for instance for the `p_house` we have a probability `1` if `time` is between `20-10=10` and `20+10=30`.

```
p_house = [20, 10]
p_bank =  [5, 1]
p_atm  =  [3, 1]
p_pharmacy = [10, 5]
```

I want to apply a function that says if is between the range of each case p=1 or p=0 otherwise. I would like to apply a function like that

```
def assignP(df):
    if ((df.time < p.case1 + mu.case) and (df.time > p.case1-mu.case)):
              df.time1 = 1
    else: 
              df.time1 = 0
    if ((df.time < p.case2 + mu.case) and (df.time > p.case2-mu.case)):
              df.time2 = 1
    else: 
              df.time2 = 0
    if ((df.time < p.case3 + mu.case) and (df.time > p.case3-mu.case)):
              df.time3 = 1
    else: 
              df.time3 = 0
    return df
```

I would like to have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
df
     time   case1   case2   case3          p1      p2     p3
0     5     house   bank     atm           0       1      0
1     3     bank    house  pharmacy        0       0      0
2     10    bank    bank     atm           0       0      0
3     15    house  pharmacy  house         1       1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should write a function for the different columns. Using `apply` you can run a simply function on the row or on the column. In that function I would determine the output value based on the average/deviation. Maybe the below can give you a start:

```py
from io import StringIO

# Create DataFrame
csvstring = StringIO("""
time case1 case2 case3
0 5 house bank atm
1 3 bank house pharmacy
2 10 bank bank atm
3 20 house pharmacy house
""")
df = pd.read_csv(csvstring, sep=" ")

p_house = [20, 10]

def get_phouse(col):
    # Split the p_house value
    (a, b) = p_house
    # If column value between the 20 - 10 or 20 + 10, return 1, otherwise 0
    return 1 if a-b < col < a+b else 0

df['phouse'] = df['time'].apply(get_phouse)
#    time  case1     case2     case3  phouse
# 0     5  house      bank       atm       0
# 1     3   bank     house  pharmacy       0
# 2    10   bank      bank       atm       0
# 3    20  house  pharmacy     house       1
```